# fputcsv seems to be producing garbage

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

Could someone let me know what I've missed here.

I have this CSV producing code:

```
    //for loop generating non empty $output array
    fputcsv($file, $output, ',', '"');
            }//end of for
            fclose($file);

        ob_clean();
        flush();
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type:text/csv;charset=UTF-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename(getcwd().'../../../tmp/signup_download.csv'));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0'); 
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize(getcwd().'../../../tmp/signup_download.csv'));
        readfile(getcwd().'../../../tmp/signup_download.csv');
        exit;
```

While it appears to be generating a reasonable result in a plain text editor like notepad, opening in openoffice just produces garbage.

Heres a sample of the created csvs:

```
test2,test2,test2@bbfwbg.com,1234,Swindon,december_2014
```

I suspect the problem is somehow in the fputcsv statement as the file otherwise generates and downloads fine.

Comment: Does it also mess up the lines when you preview it in openOffice? Here you can read about a bug in openOffice http://grokbase.com/p/php/php-bugs/101bh5bvag/50686-wfx-fputcsv-and-fgetcsv-doesnt-follow-csv-format

Comment: I landed here after having a similar issue. My source data was multi-byte (which I did not need), so I fixed with $line = mb_convert_encoding(trim($line), 'UTF-8');